# ES6: Unable to access a function inside $(document).delegate()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

I am using ES6 and have a problem, showCarOnMap() that a part of instance is not accessible inside $(document).delegate() or $(document).click()

> Actually I have a table and found the row number after click through $(document).delegate() by "$(this).index()" and I want to call showCarOnMap() function after founding the clicked row number.
>   but this time 'this' is not having showCarOnMap();

Please see the comments for better understanding.

```
import {Page} from './framework/page.js';
import {DataTable} from './ui/data-table.js';
import {application} from './app.js';
import {GoogleMap} from './ui/google-map.js';
import {Button} from './ui/button.js';


export class CarsPage extends Page{
    constructor(){
        super('Cars');
    }

    createElement(){
        super.createElement();
        //passing headers and data to genrate the table of car
        let headers = 'License Make Model Miles Track'.split(' ');
        let t = new DataTable(headers, application.dataService.cars); 
        t.appendToElement(this.element);

        /* Poblem Start here*/
        $(document).delegate("tr", "click", function(e) {
            let index = $(this).index(); // getting right index   
            this.showCarOnMap(index); // BUT: not getting showCarOnMap() 
            //Uncaught TypeError: this.showCarOnMap is not a function
        });
    }

    showCarOnMap(index){
        // car on map
        let mapArray = [];
        mapArray.push(application.dataService.cars[index]);
        let centerOfMap = {lat: 40.783661, lng: -73.965883};
        let carLabelObject = {titleOfCar:'Car', titleOfDrone:'Drone'};
        let carMap = new GoogleMap(centerOfMap, mapArray, carLabelObject);
        carMap.appendToElement(this.element);
    }

    getElementString(){
        return '<div style="margin:20px;"><h3>Cars</h3></div>';
    }
}
```

I tried one another way-
But not working

```
$(document).delegate("tr", "click",(e)=>{
    let index = $(this).index();  // wrong: index always -1
    this.showCarOnMap(index); // founded in this });
```

Comment: `this` is not both `tr` element and `CarsPage` instance at the same time

Comment: @guest271314 Yes, I know but to resolve this problem.
Please help

Comment: `this` is also `document` within arrow function

Comment: @guest271314 Actually when I call directly showCarOnMap(0) or showCarOnMap(1) then this is fine.
But according to my flow of project how can I solve this problem.

Comment: createElement(){
        super.createElement();
        //passing headers and data to genrate the table of car
        let headers = 'License Make Model Miles Track'.split(' ');
        let t = new DataTable(headers, application.dataService.cars); 
        t.appendToElement(this.element);

       showCarOnMap(1);
    }

This is working fine.

Comment: Use `event.target` within event handler arrow function to reference current `<tr>` element

Comment: what. Why would you expect `this` to be both the table row that was clicked AND an instance of the class? it can only be one or the other..

Comment: @KevinB Actually I want to call showCarOnMap(clickedTrNumber)
Or I want to click on row and find that ow number and and call showCarOnMap(clickedTrNumber)
How can I achieve.

Please help

Comment: @KevinB Dear do you have any idea about how to achieve the solution of my problem

Comment: Yes, access `this` correctly, and access the clicked element correctly. problem solved

Comment: How?
Could you please write a piece of code.

Comment: There's no reason for me to, one has already been provided by someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `event.target.parentElement` or `.closest()` to reference clicked `<tr>` element.

Or, as suggested by @KevinB, `event.currentTarget`

```
  $(document).on("click", "tr", event => {
    // or `$(event.target).closest("tr").index()`
    // or `$(event.currentTarget).index()`
    let index = $(event.target.parentElement).index();
    this.showCarOnMap(index);
  });
```

Comment: @KevinB _"no it isn't."_ Yes, it is, given code at OP http://plnkr.co/edit/fUi2O8NMc0QIJTvaZpm2?p=preview

Comment: @KevinB Just noticed that. `this` would still not be `tr` element http://plnkr.co/edit/fUi2O8NMc0QIJTvaZpm2?p=preview. The solution is still to use `event.target` to reference clicked `<tr>` element. See updated post, removed erroneous portion of Answer

Comment: Index always 0 but yes able to call showCarOnMap(clickedTrNumber)

Comment: @AnkitPandey See updated post. The clicked element was the `<td>` element. To reference `<tr>` element you can use `event.target.parentElement` or `$(event.target).closest("tr").index()`

Comment: why is parentElement needed? wouldn't jquery set the event target to the tr in this case?

Comment: @KevinB No, evidently not. `event.target` can be a `<td>` child element of parent `<tr>` element http://plnkr.co/edit/fUi2O8NMc0QIJTvaZpm2?p=preview at version 3

Comment: you are correct. it's [`e.currentTarget`](http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/) that i was thinking about, which would be equivalent to `this` in the non-arrow function version.

Comment: @guest271314  $(event.target).closest("tr").index()  is working fine for me
Thanks a lot.

Comment: @KevinB Updated post to reflect the inclusion of `event.currentTarget` option